# git after init and push? I need to clone a new?

Tags: git, svn

I am not a skilled.
in ssh server, I create :

```
$ mkdir project.git
$ cd project.git
$ git --bare init
```

and then in my pc:

```
$ cd myproject
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'initial commit'
$ git remote add origin git@gitserver:/opt/git/project.git
$ git push origin master
```

all thing is ok.
in old days (i learn from svn), i remove myproject and then clone ,and start my work.

```
git clone git@gitserver:/opt/git/project.git
```

can i start work in myproject folder?

Comment: what's your question exactly?

Comment: can i start work in myproject work?

Comment: http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove and clone your project after push. It's already ready to be worked on, and linked to your remote.

To shorten things, once the repository is created on the server you could have done directly :

```
$ cd myproject
$ git clone git@gitserver:/opt/git/project.git
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'initial commit'
$ git push origin master
```

Because a `git clone` automatically sets `origin` to the repository which was cloned.

Comment: How is `git clone` supposed to succeed when the project doesn't exist on the server, yet?

Comment: I assume that of course creation has happened, making it clearer

Comment: I think the point of this question is: "How do I create a new repo on the remote server *and* attach my local copy at the same time?"

Answer (score 0):

I think one small change in your steps would get you what you want:

```
$ cd myproject
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'initial commit'
$ git remote add origin git@gitserver:/opt/git/project.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

Notice in the last step the `-u` flag.  That sets `master` to track the `master` branch of the upstream repository.  After doing this, your repository will have the same configuration as if you had cloned it.